# How to use Visual Studio 11 Dark Theme on my own WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, themes

Does anyone know how to use Visual Studio 11 Dark Theme in my own WPF application? I mean the color and design of the controls. (I code using VS 11 too)

Visual Studio team themselves say this :

> > As a part of the Visual Studio 11 overall release plan we will be making all of the icons for this release available to you in multiple file formats including vector. You are free to take full advantage of the easy theme-ability and resize-ability of these assets within your own applications.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/05/29/visual-studio-dark-theme.aspx (Last paragraph in Themed Icons section)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I actually was just looking for the same thing for the WPF app that I am working on. I couldn't find one but did find a VS 2012 Metro Style Theme.

Someone posted it here : [VS Theme](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442856/Visual-Studio-2012-Metro-Styles-for-WPF)

Comment: Seems there's no difference between Dark & Metro. Or it is?

Comment: It seems I got some problem, after editing the App.xaml, there's error message `Assembly Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles is not referenced by this project`. Why is that? (I'm new on such things) Btw, I've tried to add existing project and adding Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles with the project dependencies, but it doesn't do any good.

Comment: in whichever project App.Xaml resides, you might need to declare dependencies.

Comment: I have declared the dependencies, but there're 3 errors `The type reference cannot find a public type named 'AppTreeContainer'. Line 218 Position 107.` , `The name "AppTreeItem" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Selen.Wpf.GenericAppTree;assembly=Selen.Wpf.GenericAppTree".` and `The name "AppTreeContainer" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Selen.Wpf.GenericAppTree;assembly=Selen.Wpf.GenericAppTree".` (error on the style project) Is it possible that I referenced a wrong project? (unlikely I think)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a wpf / xaml dark theme or dark mode (or any other color), use the [MahApps.Metro](https://mahapps.com/) UI toolkit. It replaces a lot of the default WPF controls with Metro styled ones that you can give all sorts of custom colors and themes.

[image]

[image]